# Android: pass object from collection widget through to activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-pendingintent, parcelable

I have a stack widget for my application which currently just launches the main activity when the widget is clicked.
I am wanting to change this so the main activity is given information about the widgetitem which was clicked. 
The object which I want to pass through implements Parcelable and can be successfully passed via an intent from a notification. However, it always seems to be null when bundled in an intent from the widget.

Any ideas?

**StackWidgetProvider**

```
     // set intent for item click (opens main activity)
        Intent viewIntent = new Intent(context, DealPadActivity.class);
        viewIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
        viewIntent.setData(Uri.parse(viewIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        PendingIntent viewPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, viewIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        rv.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.stack_view, viewPendingIntent);
```

**StackWidgetService**

```
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {

    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.stack_widget_item);
    if (position < mWidgetItems.size()){
        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.stack_widget_title, mWidgetItems.get(position).title);
        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.stack_widget_price, mWidgetItems.get(position).price);
        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.stack_widget_heat, mWidgetItems.get(position).heat);
        Bitmap picture = imageLaoder.getBitmap(mWidgetItems.get(position).imageUrl, true) ;
        rv.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.stack_widget_image, picture);
    }

    Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putInt(StackWidgetProvider.EXTRA_ITEM, position);
    extras.putParcelable("notificationDeal", new Deal(...));
    fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);

    rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.stack_widget_layout, fillInIntent);
    return rv;
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
    Bundle data = queryIntent.getExtras(); 

    if  (data!=null){ // check to see if from widget or notification
    Deal deal = data.getParcelable("notificationDeal");
            if (deal!=null){ // ****ALWAYS NULL FROM WIDGET**** 
                Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "going to show passed deal");
                onDealSelected(deal);
            }
            int i = data.getInt("com.bencallis.dealpad.stackwidget.EXTRA_ITEM");
            Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "pressed widget is: " + i); **WIDGET ITEM POSITION AS EXPECTED **
```

** Update **

It seems it is a problem with marshalling (unmarshalling specifically)

```
E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.bencallis.abc.Deal, e: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bencallis.abc.Deal
```

I have imported the Deal class into the StackWidgetService and I have tried to set the class loader but this does not seem to help.

The Deal parable is being used successfully within the main activities of the app, I just have this problem with the widget.

Deal class

```
public Deal(Parcel in) {
    in.readParcelable(Deal.class.getClassLoader());
}


@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(title);
    ...
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
    public Deal createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Deal(in);
    }

    public Deal[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Deal[size];
    }
};
```

Comment: Well... Is the intent that you're receiving the same that you sent? Why don't you try to set an action to the Intent and confirm if the action of the received intent is the action that you put when you sent it? The only reason I can think for you to get a null "Deal" is that you're not receiving the intent you expect to receive.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with unmarshalling as the class can not be found. I have tried to set the Class loader but i'm not having any luck. Please see the update.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you've tried to set the class loader. That should work. I'm not sure how you've tried to set the class loader because you've not provided that code. Try this:

In `MainActivity`, insert this:

```
ClassLoader loader = Deal.class.getClassLoader();
queryIntent.setExtrasClassLoader(loader);
```

before this:

```
Bundle data = queryIntent.getExtras();
```